# Javascript create a responsive container

Tags: javascript, html, containers

I have an older website that I need to be made more dynamic. The website has a graphic chart that is nested inside a div. The problem I have is that there is  javascript code that hard codes the height and width of the div container. I tried changing the size amount(350) to auto and percentage(10%) but it breaks the program. I can't figure out how the program converts the integer value to a pixel value either, but that's probably just my incompetence with javascript. I may have missed some important information so let me know if you need anything else. Thanks

**Javascript**

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'conKinetic',
    width: 1100,
    height: 350
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='fourthDiv' id="conKinetic">
    ....This div holds the graphics
</div>
```

Comment: if the class is actually `fourthDiv` I would advise you to immediately remove the class because it goes against EVERY convention and will certainly kill the maintainability.

Comment: you should also check the documentation about using [Kinetic.js](http://kineticjs.com/) if you want to manipulate the layout of the canvas inside the container.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery, you can set the width and height as percentage and then pass the current pixel units in this way:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'conKinetic',
    width: $('#conKinetic').width(),
    height: $('#conKinetic').height()
});
```

Of course, you can edit the `width` or `height` values to adapt them to your layout:

```
width: $('#conKinetic').width() - 50,
```

Consider this example:

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('body').append( 'My width is 50%, equivalent to ' + $( '#hi' ).width() + ' px.');
});
```

```css
body { width: 100%; }
#hi { width: 50%; background-color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hi">hello!</div>
```

Hope it helps!